# How to run cmd as administrator (from a non-admin account)?

Tags: cmd, admin

Is it possible to somehow make cmd run as Admin without being prompted for credentials ?

I am looking for a command to do so which I can use in my java program
(If at all it is possible)

Comment: Which operating system are you talking about? Linux/OSX or Windows?

Comment: I want to do it on a Windows machine